# Add a default value to a form input field

Tags: html, regex, validation, forms, html-input

I have a form for an online loan application. In the field for the loan period, i need to ensure that the user types in "months" or "Months" when they are typing in the amount of months. eg. 36 months.

I have created a regex for this(`.[Mm]onths?` - my first attempt at creating a regex), but i feel that it could be rather annoying for the user to have to go back to the field and input the word "months".

Is it at all possible to have the word "months" pre-inserted into the field or inserted after editing the field/form submission? I already have placeholder text("EX: 36 Months") but it disappears when the input field is selected. I need the text "months" to be a part of the actual text that is being input.

I have done a quick search on the net, I know there is an answer somewhere but I cant seem to find the correct search terms to use as I have not come across a solution as yet.

Any advice on this matter? If i cannot have the text "months" included into the input in any way, I will have to use the regex.

Comment: Do this on server side validation?

Comment: I wouldn't have months in the input, but rather in the label/after the input.  Then you just need integer validation on the field.  If you need to add the literal "months" down the line, add it after you've validated the integer.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - any way i can. Server or client side.

Comment: @John -how would i add the word after the user inputs the integer?

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to do this in server side validation, use a form like the following:

```html
<input type="number" name="months" /> months
```

and later, in the server code; you'll do (assuming PHP):

```php
$mon = $_REQUEST['months'] . " months";
```

Comment: This would work, but if the user inputs "36 Months", i will end up with "36 Months months"... I think i will be better off using regex.

Comment: The user can not enter `36 Months` for a `input type="number"` element.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However the wordpress plugin i am using does not use type="number", only type="text". I found it  a little frustrating as i cannot have a number field. I really do appreciate your input and assistance, thank you.

Comment: FSCF - Fast Secure Contact Form

Comment: @Kbam7 The FAQs suggest that it is possible: http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/how-to-add-extra-fields

Comment: It is possible to add extra fields, but when selecting which field to add, there is no `number` option. Trust me, I have looked. :) I know i could probably change the type via JavaScript, but it might interfere with the functionality of the plugin as its not a standard feature.

Comment: In that case, you can check whether the input already contains `month`: `$mon = $_REQUEST['months'] . (stristr($_REQUEST['months'], "month")?"":" months");`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `36 Months months` should the user find a crooked way to input it or is using an older browser that doesn't support `type="number"`, you should consider extending your PHP. Say by type casting to get only first integer and prepending "months" to it

```
$months =  (int) $_REQUEST["months"] . " months";
//Input '36 Months'. Output '36 months'
//Input 'Months36'. Output '0 months'
```

Or by removing every character that does not constitute a number and prepending "months" to it

```
$months =  preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $_REQUEST["months"]) . " months";
//Input '36 Months'. Output '36 months'
//Input 'Months36'. Output '36 months'
//Input 'Man3Bad6'. Output '36 months'
//Input 'Gone3g6F.ullstop5'. Output '36.5 months'
```